# Getting an object using objectId

Tags: parse-platform

That must be a more than simple question, but whatever I try does not work.
And I can see no answer to this precise question anywhere on the net.

In a Parse Cloud function:
How do I retrieve an object from a class, when I know its objectId?

This code doesn't work

```
var query = new Parse.Query("MyClass");
query.equalTo("objectId", myObjectId);
query.find
({...
```

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging and trial here is the solution I found. Though a bit more complicated than what I was hoping for, it does the job. So I thought it may be useful for someone else too.

```
 var query = new Parse.Query("MyClass");
 query(myObjectId, {
                success: function(object) {
                // Code in case of success.
                response.success();
                },
                error: function(object, error) {
                // Code in case of failure.
                response.error(“It failed”);
                }
                });
```